# SQL Server Insert query

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

This is a simplified version of my issue. I have 2 tables below

```
ProductInformtaionType

ProductInformationTypeID  Name     isText  isInteger  isDecimal is Boolean
1                         barcode    1        0           0        0
2                         Vatable    0        0           0        1
3                         Quantity   0        1           0        0
```

and

```
ProductInformtaion

ProductInformtaion  ProductID   ProductInformtaionTypeID  ValueText   ValueInteger ValueDecimal
```

when i get some values i need an insert query which will insert the data in the relavant field. e.g quantity is integer so I need to insert that product into the productinformation table and only populate the isIntegerfield

How do I create a dynamic insert query which populates the correct field instead of wringing 4 seperate inserts for (istext, isInteger, isBoolean, isDecimal) with the where istext = 1 clause

Comment: So what is the actual question here?

Comment: Please google and learn about the INSERT command in SQL.

Comment: INSERT with a SELECT.   Write a select that returns the column you need for the insert, join to the type table and use a CASE for text, integer, decimal columns.  test and get the query working, then prefix that select with `INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2,...)` and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.  Make a stored procedure that accepts all the parameters.  Then, just pass it NULL values.  For example, to insert only 'Column3', you would call:

```
Exec dbo.[Test_Stored_Procedure] @Column3 = 'hey!!!'
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
Exec dbo.[Test_Stored_Procedure] @Column1 = null, @Column2 = null, @Column3 = 'hey!!!', @Column4 = null
```

Here is the Stored Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_Stored_Procedure]
    @Column1 varchar(50) = null,
    @Column2 varchar(50) = null,
    @Column3 varchar(50) = null,
    @Column4 varchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YourTable
    VALUES
    (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3, @Column4)
END
```